# Are jumps of $C^2$ cadlag functions finite variation? Why are the discontinuous parts of Ito formula of finite variation?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Below is an excerpt from the proof of Ito's formula in the following post :https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/#scn_genito_eq3

We assume $f$ to be a real $C^2$ function from some open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $X$ is a $d$-dimensional semimartingale.

The statement below states that the terms inside the sum $$\Delta f(X_t) - D_i f(X_{t-})\Delta X_t^i - \frac{1}{2}D_{ij}f(X_{t-})\Delta X_t^i \Delta X_t^j$$ are all finite variation processes.

Why is this the case? I am not familiar with any thoerem stating that jumps of cadlag functions are of bounded variation. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could clear this up for me.

[image]